# How to configure Linux iptables to block a specific port of server?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

I am trying to implement port restricted cone NAT. I want to block a specific port 3479 of server 192.168.10.102.
`iptables -A INPUT -i $WAN -p udp -s 192.168.10.102 --sport 3479 -j DROP`
`iptables -A INPUT -i $WAN -p tcp -s 192.168.10.102 --sport 3479 -j DROP`

But I am still able get packets from this port on client side. What exactly am I doing wrong? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Use IPtables

iptables -A INPUT -i {INTRFACE} -p tcp --destination-port 3479 -s 192.168.10.203 -j DROP

INTERFACE would be either eth0 or eth1.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the source ports are randomly generated unless you have specifically defined. So a better way to block certain port at destination side.

You can reference to the answer Rakesh Pant suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to say why its failing without seeing a full output of the rules, but my guess is that this rule is being inserted after a more permissive rule allowing it.

Note that you have used "-A" which appends the rule to the end of the table.  If you use "-I" instead it will prepend it which is probably what you want.